# Encountered (Warning: Illegal string offset) while creating a configuration sytem for a site

Tags: php, string, configuration

I like this kind of configuration because it's more cleaner therefore I have a configuration file with the following:

```
<?php
 $Config['option_1'] = 'some value';
 $Config['option_2'] = 'some value';
 $Config['option_3'] = 'some value';
?>
```

Then i have a class with a method to load this kind of configuration files It's very similar with how CodeIgniter loads the configuration files except when i include this file I get:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'option_1' in 'Path to the config file' on line #.
Warning: Illegal string offset 'option_2' in 'Path to the config file' on line #.
Warning: Illegal string offset 'option_3' in 'Path to the config file' on line #.
```

etc. You get the idea.

I've searched everywhere on how to use this kind of configuration system on a site but no result. So if anyone has a link to a tutorial or some documentation on this then please help me understand how this works or why i get that error when I require the configuration file from inside a class using one of it's methods.

Note. When i load the configuration file directly into the browser I get no errors and I can successfully echo out any values using "echo $Config['option_1'];"

Comment: My best guess is somehow the `$Config` variable is getting overwritten or re-assigned as something else accidentally turning it into a string, in which case `option_1` is not a valid offset, a valid offset would then be `[0,n-1]` where `n` is the length of the string

Answer (score -3):

if you do

```
var_dump($Config);
```

you'll see that it's not an array like you think.

Comment: I've found the problem. The array was named $Config "$Config['option_1'] = 'some value';" and The function that loaded that file also had and argument named $Config in which the name of the file is passed therefore replacing the array the actual array that i needed.